# Markov Switching GARCH - Expanding or Rolling window forecasting?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, garch, volatility-forecasting, moving-window

When modelling volatility do people tend to use expanding or sliding windows to predict the performance of MS GARCH models?

Answer (score 1):

In the volatility forecasting literature most apply a rolling window approach. This is motivated by the literature on forecasting evaluation that mostly allows for fixed or rolling windows for the tests to be asymptotically valid.

Comment: This is also what I see in the academic literature. Whether the same is true among practitioners is another question (which I do not have an answer to).

Comment: Yes. I guess a lot of practioners use expanding windows.